# Trying to convert this .NET JsonConvert.Deserialize method that is using a custom JsonConverter to a JsonSerialize.Deserialize

Tags: c#, .net, json, json-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a large json file. As such, I wish to stream the file content to the `Deserialize` method to reduce the number of allocations/GC, etc.

My current deserialization method uses a custom `JsonConverter` (which works great). I'm not sure how to do this same code, but using the streaming method of a `JsonSerlialize` instance with a custom `JsonConverter`.

Current code:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<T>>(content, new[] { jsonConverter });
```

New code (incomplete):

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
    using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
    {
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        return jsonConverter == serializer.Deserialize<IList<T>>(jsonReader);
    }
}
```

My new code doesn't take any CustomConverter instances in. How can I do this, please?

Comment: Does adding your custom converter to the [`Converters`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Converters.htm) collection of your newly instantiated serializer work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the JsonSerializer's [static `Create` function with settings](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Create_1.htm) to pass your converter.

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
    using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
    {
        var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(new JsonSerializerSettings() { Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { jsonConverter }});
        return jsonConverter == serializer.Deserialize<IList<T>>(jsonReader);
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up putting my custom JsonConverter as an attribute over the property and stuff worked. BUT if this was a case where I couldn't decorate the class with an attribute (think -> 3rd party nuget package) then yeah .. this looks like the way.